# Python writing data to files

Tags: python, loops

I have a quick question about python coding: I have a few files with two columns (wavelength and flux) and each file was taken at different dates. So I have a file (original.txt) which has the names of the file in one column and the dates in the other column. Now, I want to read the files and add a third column of date to the "wavelength and flux" files.

So I start with original.txt which has:

```
file_a.txt 23

file_b.txt 26

file_c.txt 30
```

So all these `file_{}.txt` have two columns of wavelength vs flux, but I want to end up with a file containing wavelength, flux and date, for example for `file_a.txt` I should have:

```
5550.0 200 23

5551.0 123 23

5552.0 109 23 

....
```

I made an attempt at this, but my code (below) only writes wavelength and flux values read from the first file in `original.txt` (i.e. those from `file_a.txt`).

```
import math

wavelength = []
flux = []
file = []
MJD = []

f = open("original.txt","r")
for line in f:
  file.append(str(line.split()[0]))
  MJD.append(float(line.split()[1]))
f.close()


for i in range(len(MJD)):
  q = open("%s"%(file[i]),"r")
  for line in q:
      wavelength.append(float(line.split()[0]))
      flux.append(float(line.split()[1]))
  q.close()


for n in range(len(MJD)):
  u = open("%s_t.txt"%(file[n]),"w")
  for j in range(len(wavelength)):
      u.write("%0.3f  %0.3f   %0.3f\n" %(wavelength[j],flux[j],MJD[n]))
  u.close()
```

Anybody catch what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: There are problems with the indentation in your `for` loops. Can you edit the indentation to match the code you are running?

Comment: @roganjosh I just fixed the indentations

Comment: i can't reproduce the error but maybe you could try iterating not like  `for i in range(len(MJD)):` but more like `for singleFile in file:` and then open the file with `q = open(singleFile,"r")`. But in general at my pc the code does the correct thing...

Comment: And you could have a look at the with statement when handling with files...
a good introduction can be found here http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: I have reproduced the error but there's a couple of things going on. I'm trying to get the anticipated output whilst maintaining as much of the original code as possible. I thought it might be due to naming the list `file` but that is only one thing.

Comment: Actually, did you want to keep the concatenated outputs in the three separate files? My answer condenses it into a single output list because of "I want to end up with a file". If you need to write the date back into the original source files e.g. `file_a.txt` then I will edit my answer. Your initial code was giving me an unusual mixture of both of those possibilities :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you had a couple of things going on. Firstly, you are naming you list by the built-in `file` which can cause unexpected behaviour so avoid this. Second, your loops are falling out of sync and creating three output files. I have condensed it to write line-by-line into a file and then close the file at the end. That made it quite hard to maintain your original code structure because it was made more complicated by doing all the tasks in isolation. I think this gives your expected output.

EDIT: I couldn't decipher properly from original code output if you wanted a single output file or multiple. So I've added code for both based on your original.

```
file_names = []  # Renamed
MJD = []
wavelength = []     
flux = []

f = open("original.txt","r")
for line in f:
    file_names.append(str(line.split()[0]))
    MJD.append(float(line.split()[1]))
f.close()

# FOR MULTIPLE OUTPUT FILES

for x in range(len(file_names)):
    input_file = open('%s' % file_names[x])
    date = MJD[x] 
    output_file = open(file_names[x].replace('.txt', '') + "_t.txt", 'w')
    for line in input_file:
         wavelength = float(line.split()[0])
         flux = float(line.split()[1])
         output_file.write("%0.3f  %0.3f   %0.3f\n" % (wavelength,flux,date))
    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()


# FOR A SINGLE OUTPUT FILE

main_output = open('outputs.txt', 'w')

for x in range(len(file_names)):
    input_file = open('%s' % file_names[x])
    date = MJD[x]         
    for line in input_file:
        wavelength = float(line.split()[0])
        flux = float(line.split()[1])
        main_output.write("%0.3f  %0.3f   %0.3f\n" % (wavelength,flux,date))
    input_file.close()
main_output.close()
```

Comment: you're my hero! Thank you!

Comment: @Itumeleng89 You're welcome. If you find that this answer solves your problem then I would ask that please could you mark it as correct (click the tick next to my answer) as the question is still left open currently

Comment: I just did that. Thanks once again.